# appending random integer to a string using .concat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to append an integer gotten from a method to a string, I have tried multiple different things: `<<` and `.concat` (although the same) `+=` as well
I have chosen to make the method due to a function I'm working on that will be added later on
the problem with this code is that instead of returning `my string + firstrandomnumber + secondrandomnumber` so on so forth it only returns `my string + latestrandomnumber`

```
def machineSlot() 
  tal1= rand(0..10)
  return tal1
end
#makes the a random number

if startBool == true
  #game startof

  gameRunner=true
  puts 'pull the lever with x'
  leverPullTry =gets.chomp

  while gameRunner
    #keeps game running

    i=1
    slotThread='Your numbers are:'
    #initialise game rollcount i and string that keeps the numbers

    if leverPullTry=='x'
      slotThread.concat( machineSlot.to_s)
      #if x was entered the slotThread appends a random number

      puts slotThread
      #slotThreads current process

      puts 'pull the lever with x again'
      i+=1
      #number of rolls increased

      leverPullTry =gets.chomp
    else
      puts 'try again use type x to pull'
      leverPullTry =gets.chomp
      #user didnt manage to input anything correct

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you should move `slotThread='Your numbers are:'` outside of the while-loop?

Comment: well this is embarrasing..
thankyou for that the comment tho

Comment: hi @user2010884 was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines:

```
  slotThread.concat( machineSlot.to_s)
  #if x was entered the slotThread appends a random number

  puts slotThread
  #slotThreads current process
```

to

```
puts "#{slotThread}#{machineSlot}"
```

That's called string interpolation, something used a lot in ruby.

By the way, you're using CamelCase to name your variables and methods which is not the convention.  Not urgent but I'd check out [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) when you have time.